# How can I adjust load balancing rule by feign in spring cloud

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-feign, netflix-ribbon

As I know, feign include ribbon's function, and I prove it in my code.

When I use feign, the default rule is Round Robin Rule.
But how can I change the rule in my feign client code, is ribbon the only way?

Here is my code below, so please help.

ConsumerApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class ConsumerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

UserFeignClient .java

```
@FeignClient(name = "cloud-provider", fallback = UserFeignClient.HystrixClientFallback.class)
public interface UserFeignClient {
    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    BaseResponse findByIdFeign(@RequestParam("id") Long id);

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    BaseResponse addUserFeign(UserVo userVo);

    @Component
    class HystrixClientFallback implements UserFeignClient {
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HystrixClientFallback.class);

        @Override
        public BaseResponse findByIdFeign(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
            BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();
            response.setMessage("disable");
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        public BaseResponse addUserFeign(UserVo userVo) {
            BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();
            response.setMessage("disable");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

FeignController.java

```
@RestController
public class FeignController {

    @Autowired
    private UserFeignClient userFeignClient;

    @GetMapping("feign/{id}")
    public BaseResponse<Date> findByIdFeign(@PathVariable Long id) {
        BaseResponse response = this.userFeignClient.findByIdFeign(id);
        return response;
    }

    @GetMapping("feign/user/add")
    public BaseResponse<Date> addUser() {
        UserVo userVo = new UserVo();
        userVo.setAge(19);
        userVo.setId(12345L);
        userVo.setUsername("nick name");
        BaseResponse response = this.userFeignClient.addUserFeign(userVo);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR5/#_customizing_the_ribbon_client):

```
@RibbonClient(name = "cloud-provider", configuration = CloudProviderConfiguration.class)
public class ConsumerApplication { 
    /* ... */
}

class CloudProviderConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
        return new RandomRule();
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I have multiple provider, how can I config RibbonClient?

Comment: I got it. Just use @RibbonClients.

Comment: @Gabriel.ge,do you mind uploading source code in github.
Thank you!

Comment: @Prash , here is the gtihub address.https://github.com/gabrielge/spring-cloud-consumer.git