# Is it possible to set a specified load-balance rule for ribbon at run-time?

Tags: ribbon

I want to dynamically configure load balance rule of Spring Cloud Ribbon in the Micro-Service at run time period.

I have searched on Google, office reference and Github, and found no direct solutions.

Do you have any ways to do this?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Cleaned up grammar a little.

Comment: Please take a look at this post - [How can I adjust load balancing rule by feign in spring cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505136/how-can-i-adjust-load-balancing-rule-by-feign-in-spring-cloud), hope its answer helps you.

Comment: Thx, i have seen the content of the link, But, i think that is not what i need.. i want to dynamically configure rule it is meaning i don't need to restart my Micro-Service.